# Method returning null is manipulating a final int array

Tags: java, arrays, methods, null, return

Can anybody please explain to me why a method returning null is manipulating a final int [] ?

```
 final int [] vals = {2,3};
 int [] vals2 = multiply(vals);

 for(int i : vals) System.out.println(i);


 int [] multiply(int [] in){
   for(int i = 0; i < in.length;i++){
      in[i] *= 2; 
   }
      return null;
 }
```

Ouput:
4
6

Edit:
I have noticed this behavior only in methods returning an array. The same method returning an int doesn't change the original integers value...

Full code:

```
public class Main{
    public Main(){
        int [] myList = {56, 32, 200};
        int [] newList = myList;
        bubble_sort(newList);

        for(int i : myList){ System.out.println(i); }
        System.out.println();
        for(int i : newList){ System.out.println(i); }
    }


    public int [] bubble_sort(int a[]){
        int n = a.length;
        int [] s = a;

        for (int i = 0; i < n ; i++){
                for (int j = n - 1; j >= (i+1); j--){
                    if (s[j - 1] > s[j]){
                        int t = s[j - 1];
                        s[j - 1] = s[j];
                        s[j] = t;
                    } 
                }
        }
        return null;
        // return s;
    }


    public static void main(String [] args){
        new Main();
    }
}
```

Edit:
Following code produces following output as expected: 2, 4

```
int vals = 2;
int vals2 = multiply(vals);
System.out.println(vals);
System.out.println(vals2);
int multiply(int in){ return in*2; }
```

So my question is, why does a method returning an int does not change the input value, but a method returning an array does change the inputs original value(s).

Comment: I think you mean that's the output if you actually call multiply. In the strict example you provided, the output should be 2, 3. But if you call multiply first, then you get the output you suggested

Comment: In your code, `myList` and `newList` refer to the same array, so changing one of them changes the other as well.

Answer (score 3):

Here, `final` means that the `vals` reference cannot be changed from referring to its initial array.  But it says nothing about whether the contents of the array can be changed.  As you see, they can be changed.

The `final` keyword will only stop you from assigning another array to `vals`, e.g.

```
vals = anotherArray;  // Disallowed; final
```

A solitary `return null;` is useless.  The `multiply` method should have been declared as `void`, returning nothing.

Comment: Yes i know its useless. But why is a method returning null NOT returning null?

Comment: @domizai Please post an example of this.

Comment: @domizai I'm sure you'll find that `vals2` _is_ `null`.

Comment: vals2 in your example will be null. But vals changed

Comment: vals2 will be the same output as vals.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are mutable in java

the "final" keyword only stops you from reassigning, not from changing the actual value. It literally means that if you were to write "in = someOtherArray" somewhere in your code, you'd get a compile error.

This makes it sound like the "final" keyword is useless, but it works as expected for primitive types, or any immutable object.

If I have: int i = 0; I cannot change the 0 without reassigning a value to i.

Answer (score 0):

Though you see the method returning null, the array contents are still getting modified within the multiply() method.

```
multiply(vals);
```

for(int i : vals) System.out.println(i);

Note that you are printing vals which has already been modified by the multiply method. (Java Pass by value)

Comment: But if i would use an int-return-method, it does not modify the inputs original value. An array-int-return-method does modify the inputs original value.

Comment: I simply want to multiply each item of an array and save it into a new array without modifying the original array. I mean of course i could do sty like this: `newArray[i]=vals[i]*2;` But i still prefer a method for this.

Answer (score 0):

So when i literally wanna use this method `int [] newList = bubble_sort(myList);` i mustn't modify the input value but saving each item into a new array
 `int [] s = new int[a.length]; for (int i = 0; i < n ; i++)s[i] = a[i];` 
and then i can continue to sort the new array and return it. Then the original array(myList) won't be affected.